# IdentityServer Flows

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect, identityserver3

IdentityServer supports different OpenId Connect flows that are defined in the [Flows](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/4a44a9f03879c85bbba50cc04c55fc4311436c1a/source/Core/Models/Enums.cs#L38-L69) enum and set for clients. There's also samples for each type of flow and many references to them in the docs but I could not find a simple definition list of what flows are in the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/) as if they are too obvious to explain in words. But I guess they're not. Can you please tell more about the differences of these, maybe we can add that to the docs?

So what are: **implicit** flow, **resource owner password credential** flow, **authorization code** flow, **client credentials** flow, **custom grant** flow, and **hybrid** flow? Also which ones are OAuth flows and which ones are OpenID Connect flows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I faced the same Issue, currently the work still in progress. when I finish the documentation, I might post it here. for time being: please check the draft:

[Enrich IdentityServer Documentation with OIDC and OAuth2 Flows section #73](https://github.com/IdentityServer/Documentation/issues/73)

**Update:** [OIDC and OAuth2 Flows](https://gist.github.com/jawadatgithub/638c11f08ecc0d76b05c)

Comment: Also see this [introduction to OAuth 2.0](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) by DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 24):

*From leastPrivilage's first link:* and [Aharon Paretzki's OAuth 2 Simplified](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified)

Flows decide how the ***ID token*** (i.e. the authorization code) and the ***Access token*** (i.e. 'the token') are returned to the client:

**Authorization Code Flow**: OAuth 2.0 flow in which

- an Authorization Code is returned from the Authorization Endpoint
- and all tokens (as a second stage, in exchange for the authorization code) are returned from the Token Endpoint
- Used for server based calls (APIs) that can maintain the confidentiality of their client secret. Allows for stronger security, as long as no-one can access the "client secret".

**Implicit Flow**: OAuth 2.0 flow in which

- all tokens are returned directly from the Authorization Endpoint
- and neither the Token Endpoint nor an Authorization Code are used.
- Used for mobile and web based apps, that cannot maintain the confidentiality of the client secret, so there is a need to have the token issued by the auth server itself. This is less secure, and it is recommended that the server should be set to deny *implicit flow* calls for API usage, and allow it only for the browser based and mobile based apps.

**Hybrid Flow**: OAuth 2.0 flow in which

- an Authorization Code is returned from the Authorization Endpoint,
- some tokens are returned directly from the Authorization Endpoint, and others are returned (as a second stage, in exchange for the authorization code) from the Token Endpoint.
- Used where both flows are needed.

Answer (score 12):

see the specifications - it has been all written down already:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html
and
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

in addition i've recently written a summary that breaks it down for different application types:

http://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/17/which-openid-connectoauth-2-o-flow-is-the-right-one/

Comment: I know but I was looking for a shorter description. I found [this](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/10/10/openid-connect-hybrid-flow-and-identityserver-v3/) description in your blog very useful.

Comment: I also find this is the biggest problem with Identity Server in that there's limited basic information about the product.  A month or so into implementing the framework the extremely detailed docs will prove useful but the learning curve isn't steep it's vertical.

Comment: I've actually learnt more about Identity Server through Auth0.com implementation docs and then coming back to Identity Server.

Comment: There also a gaping whole in the docs on how this fits in with native mobile apps.  I intend to implement with Xamarin and blog my findings.

Comment: Feel free to write that all up and let us know so we can link to it. It is not a product, it is OSS. Moaning is easy. Improve it yourself.

Comment: You're right.  I shouldn't moan.  It's a great resource, hope I can contribute.

Comment: IdentityServer is one of the best documented projects I have worked with. There are dozens of easy to follow examples here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source. Thanks @leastprivilege !

Answer (score 8):

The flows defined in [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) are just several ways for a client to receive an `access token` from an identity provider server; the `IdentityServer` in this case. Understanding the flows won't be easy unless you fully comprehend the entities specified in [the flow diagrams](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) such as `Resource Owner`, `User Agent`, and `Resource Server`. There're some brief explanations on these entities ( roles, preciously ) in [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1).

---

**Authorization code flow** : issues an `authorization code` prior to issuing an `access token`.

- A client requests an `authorization code.`
- *IdentityServer* Validates the client and asks the resource owner to grant the authorization to issue an `authorization code`.
- The client then requests an `access token` with the given `authorization code`
- *The authorization server* issues an `access token` directly to the client.

---

**Implicit code flow** : issues an `access token` even with no `authorization code` provided.

- A client requests an `access token` directly.
- *IdentityServer* skips validating the client ( in some scenarios, it partially does ) but still asks the resource owner to grant the authorization to issue an `access token`
- This flow never issues an `authorization code`.

**Implicit flow** is considered as the ideal flow for a client using script languages like `javascript` since the client doesn't have to request for an `authorization code` and an `access token` separately, in turn, reducing one network round trip for the client.

---

**Client credentials flow** : issues an `access token` without a resource owner's permission.

- A client requests an access token directly.
- *IdentityServer* validates the client and issues an `access token` right away.

This is ideal when the client is also a resource owner, so it doesn't need any authorization permissions all the way down to the `access token`.

---

**Resource owner flow** : issues an `access token` if a client has the resource owner's credentials ( eg. Id / Password )

- A client requests an `access token` directly.
- *IdentityServer* validates the client and checks the resource owner's identity.
- If valid, the client gets `access token` instantly.

This flow is ideal for the clients that you believe it is *absolutely* safe to share the ids and passwords with them.

---

**Hybrid flow (OIDC flow)** : issues an `authorization code` and an `access token`.

This is a combination of `Authorization code flow` and `Implicit code flow`. That's why it's called `Hybrid`.

---

**Custom flow**

This is literally a customizable flow. This can be used when you need a specific authentication / validation process in your business beside all the protocol specifications in `OAuth2`.

*IdentityServer* is well aware of this kind of situation and it supports extensibilities by design. The factory pattern, the decorator pattern, and IoC / DI will be making easier for you to implement additional features on your *IdentityServer*.